# Palabra "sabatismo"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones

Cita de *Cuestiones Místicas* por el p. Gonzalez Arintero, alto de la p. 173 :

> Todos los días, nos advierte el Apóstol (Hebr., 3, 13, 14;
> 4, 1-12), se nos invita a entrar en ese *descanso*; para
> nosotros ha quedado este *sabatismo*: *apresurémonos*, pues, a
> entrar en él, y no seamos incrédulos.

(en https://archive.org/details/cuestionesmsti00arinuoft/page/173/mode/1up )

No encontré la palabra *sabatismo* en mis diccionários.
O trecho "*para nosotros ha quedado*" este sabatismo parece ser uma
parafrase de Heb. 4, 9, que na Bíblia RVR (en https://www.biblestudytools.com/rvr/hebreos/4.html) está como "*Por tanto, queda un reposo para el pueblo de Dios*".
Entonces, ¿ sabatismo seriá sinónimo de reposo/descanso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas en lo cierto, **sabatismo** es sinónimo de reposo/descanso. Aunque en este texto se refiere al descanso que para los Cristianos y para la Iglesia representa el día de celebración, "**el Día del Señor**", donde los Cristianos se reúnen y congregan para escuchar la palabra de Dios y celebrarlo, en nuestro caso, con la misa del Domingo.

Por otro lado, **Sabático** hace referencia al *Tiempo que una persona dedica al descanso o a una actividad diferente de la habitual. Sabatino el descanso sabático de los judíos*

---

La palabra "**Sabatismo**" procede de la tradición judía, el **Shabat**, que es considerado como el **sagrado séptimo día de la semana**, y por tanto, según la Torá, se ha de celebrar abteniéndose de realizar cualquier tipo de trabajo.

Este día conmemora toda la creación de Dios y simboliza el eterno reposo que Dios dará a su pueblo, iniciado con el reino de Cristo al que le seguirá la eternidad. Este día de conmemoración y celebración es señal identificativa con el pueblo de Dios.

Así pues, tomándolo de la base del Judaísmo, el **Shabat**, paso a la tradición cristiana. El término proviene del latín "**sabbatum**" y este del hebreo. De esta manera para el Cristianismo, el día de descanso (Sabbat) fue el Domingo y para el Islam lo fue el viernes. En algunas sociedades violar el día "*del descanso dominical*" fue considerado delito.

Al final la palabra sabbat, dio el término "**sabatismo**",( *como aquello que procede del sabbat*, el día del Señor) y la palabra "**sabático**", para referirse en términos generales a todo lo relacionado con el descanso, el ocio, el relax...

> Todos los días, nos advierte el Apóstol
>
> se nos invita a entrar en ese descanso
>
> "para nosotros ha quedado este sabatismo"

**En este caso el Apóstol nos recuerda todos los días, el día de la celebración, que es el día de descanso, el día del Señor, es decir, el día en que todos los creyentes se reúnen *"para nosotros (los creyentes) ha quedado este sabatismo (entrar en este descanso)*". En el caso de los Cristianos, se refiere al "Domingo", al día de descanso, el día del Señor, el día en que se reúnen los fieles, como fundamento y recordatorio cristiano para congregarse y celebrar el día en que Jesucristo resucitó.**

> "Venite ad me omnes qui laboratis, et onerati estis, et Ego reficiam
> vos"

*"Venid a mí todos los que estáis trabajados y cargados, y yo os restauraré"*.

**Por ello el Apóstol, excita o incentiva a los creyentes y les recuerda acudir al "día de celebración" que es el día de descanso (sabatismo) para la Iglesia, el día del Señor. (LIV) "*Todos los que tengan sed vengan a mi*" (se refiere a la sed de Cristo), pues solo los que tengan sed (de Cristo)) son invitados por estas palabras "*Quien tiene sed* (de Cristo), *venga a Mi y beba. Quien no tenga sed* (sed de Cristo) *no persevera caminando*".**

> "Para nosotros ha quedado este sabatismo: apresurémonos, pues, a
> entrar en él, y no seamos incrédulos".

*Para nosotros ha quedado este sabatismo* **(este día de descanso y celebración de Dios, el Día del Señor)**: *apresurémonos, pues, a entrar en él **(acudir a él el día en que lo celebramos)**, y no seamos incrédulos **(creamos en su significado)***.

Answer (score 2):

Sabatismo es (según la [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/sabatismo)), el "descanso tomado después de un trabajo asiduo".